How to add more electrode layers between the electrode and the scattering region for graphene nanoribbons?
I am repeating results from the paper : 10.1103/PhysRevB.81.205437.
my transport device is described in the following image:

The following is part of the output.
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:   881.824   121.925     6.075   121.925     6.075 -0.810E+01
ts-Vha: -0.64145733E+00 eV
ts-scf:  200   -50050.206174   -50050.207213   -50050.207213  0.000015 -6.698277  0.003239
SCF_NOT_CONV: SCF did not converge in maximum number of steps (required).
Geom step, scf iteration, dDmax, dHmax:    0   200      0.000015     0.000238
Geom step, scf iteration, dq:    0   200   -8.101195
ABNORMAL_TERMINATION

Transiesta refused to convergence due to large dQ. After reading the previous post Transiesta scattering calculation not converging and the manual:
Always ensure that charges are preserved in the scattering region calculation. Doing the SCF an output like the following will be shown:
          ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2        dQ
          ts-q:   436.147   392.146     3.871   392.146     3.871  7.996E-3
   Always ensure the last column (dQ) is a very small fraction of the total number of 
   electrons. Ideally this should be 0. For 0 bias calculations this should be very small, 
   typically less than 0.1 % of the total charge in the system. If this is not the case, 
   it probably means that there is not enough screening towards the electrodes which can 
   be solved by adding more electrode layers between the electrode and the scattering 
   region. This layer thickness is very important to obtain a correct open boundary 
   calculation.

To my understanding,if the electrode material and channel material are different, adding more electrode layers between the electrode and the scattering region means increasing the thickness of electrode material in the device model. Just as this post claimedregarding electrode setup in scattering region, they increase the electrode material in the scattering region from 3 layers to 6 layers.
However, in my case, my electrode material and channel material are all graphene nanoribbons. To my understanding, adding more electrode layers between the electrode and the scattering region in my situation is just to increase the nanoribbon length in the transport direction and I have tested the nanoribbon length from around 33 angstroms to around 77 angstroms and keep the electrode unit cell calculations unchanged. Transiesta always refused to convergence even if scf iteration is set to 1000.
I can share all the input and output files if needed.
Any suggestion will be appreciated!

The problem is finally solved by using an extremely large device or we can say, an extremely long screening layer, which is 128.205 angstroms in the transport direction. I think the underlying principle is that the electronic structure of graphene nanoribbon I used is special so that such a long screening layer towards to electrode is needed.
Here is part of the output file
transiesta: Charge distribution, target =   1920.00000
Total charge                  [Q]  :   1920.00000
Device                        [D]  :   1658.05875
Left                          [E1] :   122.05856
Left                 / device [C1] :     5.94155
Right                         [E2] :   122.05877
Right                / device [C2] :     5.94083
Other                         [O]  :      5.94154
Excess charge                [dQ]  :  6.82121E-13

ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.563   122.059     5.955   122.059     5.957  0.533E+00
ts-Vha: -0.19945005E+00 eV


From where we can see dQ/D is way less 0.1% as suggested by manual.
And transiesta decided to convergence after 27 iterations.
        iscf     Eharris(eV)        E_KS(eV)     FreeEng(eV)     dDmax    Ef(eV) dHmax(eV)
ts-scf:    1   -83687.586297   -83683.601369   -83683.601369  0.002804 -6.655160  0.323281
timer: Routine,Calls,Time,% = TS             1       2.201   0.79
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.206   122.059     5.953   122.059     5.954  0.173E+00
ts-Vha:  0.25220166E+00 eV
ts-scf:    2   -83678.506689   -83681.112970   -83681.112970  0.001833 -6.655160  0.565276
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.398   122.059     5.953   122.059     5.954  0.363E+00
ts-Vha: -0.26295177E+00 eV
ts-scf:    3   -83683.540450   -83682.367941   -83682.367941  0.001554 -6.655160  0.545346
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.256   122.059     5.951   122.059     5.952  0.217E+00
ts-Vha: -0.79699332E-01 eV
ts-scf:    4   -83680.286454   -83681.324040   -83681.324040  0.000951 -6.655160  0.168733
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.138   122.059     5.948   122.059     5.948  0.931E-01
ts-Vha: -0.54999614E-01 eV
ts-scf:    5   -83679.414869   -83680.366677   -83680.366677  0.000704 -6.655160  0.110667
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.110   122.059     5.946   122.059     5.946  0.619E-01
ts-Vha: -0.58127753E-01 eV
ts-scf:    6   -83679.809718   -83680.087453   -83680.087453  0.000370 -6.655160  0.124632
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.092   122.059     5.945   122.059     5.944  0.407E-01
ts-Vha: -0.61712559E-01 eV
ts-scf:    7   -83679.693965   -83679.890180   -83679.890180  0.000303 -6.655160  0.111656
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.086   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.311E-01
ts-Vha: -0.47051355E-01 eV
ts-scf:    8   -83679.624566   -83679.757426   -83679.757426  0.000552 -6.655160  0.067212
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.091   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.353E-01
ts-Vha: -0.46829368E-01 eV
ts-scf:    9   -83679.806400   -83679.782080   -83679.782080  0.000266 -6.655160  0.057358
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.090   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.345E-01
ts-Vha: -0.32505424E-01 eV
ts-scf:   10   -83679.789965   -83679.786068   -83679.786068  0.000228 -6.655160  0.029455
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.081   122.059     5.944   122.059     5.943  0.266E-01
ts-Vha: -0.13357572E-01 eV
ts-scf:   11   -83679.712851   -83679.749442   -83679.749442  0.000133 -6.655160  0.014303
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.097   122.059     5.944   122.059     5.943  0.424E-01
ts-Vha: -0.53652554E-01 eV
ts-scf:   12   -83679.966142   -83679.858314   -83679.858314  0.000155 -6.655160  0.063664
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.074   122.059     5.944   122.059     5.943  0.189E-01
ts-Vha:  0.38420880E-02 eV
ts-scf:   13   -83679.543997   -83679.701392   -83679.701392  0.000215 -6.655160  0.045591
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.084   122.059     5.944   122.059     5.943  0.288E-01
ts-Vha: -0.22261408E-01 eV
ts-scf:   14   -83679.835802   -83679.768749   -83679.768749  0.000103 -6.655160  0.005759
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.084   122.059     5.944   122.059     5.943  0.288E-01
ts-Vha: -0.22383334E-01 eV
ts-scf:   15   -83679.767584   -83679.768166   -83679.768166  0.000012 -6.655160  0.005854
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.084   122.059     5.944   122.059     5.943  0.289E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21645667E-01 eV
ts-scf:   16   -83679.765545   -83679.766858   -83679.766858  0.000065 -6.655160  0.003406
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.084   122.059     5.944   122.059     5.942  0.289E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21837457E-01 eV
ts-scf:   17   -83679.762317   -83679.764589   -83679.764589  0.000056 -6.655160  0.003810
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.084   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.286E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21598544E-01 eV
ts-scf:   18   -83679.757419   -83679.761002   -83679.761002  0.000044 -6.655160  0.002764
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.084   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.290E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21373600E-01 eV
ts-scf:   19   -83679.766592   -83679.763801   -83679.763801  0.000026 -6.655160  0.002159
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.085   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.292E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21434165E-01 eV
ts-scf:   20   -83679.766515   -83679.765160   -83679.765160  0.000003 -6.655160  0.002365
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.085   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.295E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21363837E-01 eV
ts-scf:   21   -83679.768984   -83679.767076   -83679.767076  0.000024 -6.655160  0.001944
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.085   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.296E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21431523E-01 eV
ts-scf:   22   -83679.766749   -83679.766913   -83679.766913  0.000017 -6.655160  0.001893
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.085   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.292E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21458726E-01 eV
ts-scf:   23   -83679.760664   -83679.763784   -83679.763784  0.000007 -6.655160  0.001806
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.085   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.290E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21423019E-01 eV
ts-scf:   24   -83679.760820   -83679.762301   -83679.762301  0.000003 -6.655160  0.001667
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.084   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.290E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21386065E-01 eV
ts-scf:   25   -83679.761405   -83679.761852   -83679.761852  0.000004 -6.655160  0.001528
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.085   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.291E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21279649E-01 eV
ts-scf:   26   -83679.762569   -83679.762212   -83679.762212  0.000024 -6.655160  0.001155
ts-q:         D        E1        C1        E2        C2         dQ
ts-q:  1658.084   122.059     5.943   122.059     5.942  0.289E-01
ts-Vha: -0.21132338E-01 eV
ts-scf:   27   -83679.759859   -83679.761034   -83679.761034  0.000006 -6.655160  0.000894

SCF Convergence by DM+H+dQ criterion
max |DM_out - DM_in|         :     0.0000055411
max |H_out - H_in|      (eV) :     0.0008937851
     Q(TS) - Q(dev)          :     0.0288849262
SCF cycle converged after 27 iterations


The inspiration for using ultra long screening layer came from the answer of Dr. nick papior in this post Transiesta convergence, where he claimed
   The last one dq, can be quite difficult to achieve, and it requires 
   some "feeling" for the system. Generally dq convergence can be 
   achieved by extending the system so that it the scattering region is 
   better screened off. 

Also,as suggested by Dr. nick papior in the postTransiesta with siesta version 4.1.5 not converging
   Again, problems are best understood by testing additional 
   layers, then playing with SCF parameters, once a convergence 
   can be reached, then one can go back to smaller systems and 
   check if the same physics can be obtained with a smaller system


I found that this is actually not related to the screening layer, but to the method of making the input file of the device. I will write a tutorial on how to make the input file of the device for reference later.
